# Prove that X is complete

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let (X,d) be a metric space. Suppose that every epsilon neighborhood of every point has a compact closure. Prove that X is complete.

Comment: Well, compact metric spaces are complete, so your space is "locally complete". Now, since the notion of convergent and Cauchy sequences are local, you can easily conclude that $X$ is complete.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627667/every-compact-metric-space-is-complete

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Every Cauchy sequence can be fit into the compact closure of *some* neighborhood.

Any sequence in a compact space has a convergent subsequence.

---

Suppose that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Select $N$ such that $d(x_m,x_n)<1$ for $m,n \geq N$.

All but finitely many elements of the sequence fall in a ball of radius $1$ about $x_N$, and therefore within its compact closure. Conclude that the Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence. Thus, $x_n$ converges.

So, every Cauchy sequence in $X$
converges. So, $X$ is complete.

Comment: can you explain by proof? really need the explaining by proof

Comment: Well, then you really need to show what you've done so far. Edit your question to indicate what you've tried.

Comment: And, if you haven't been able to do anything at all, then this hint is a good starting point.

Comment: i have an assignment due in an hour. I cant try anything right now. Please help?

Comment: See my edit.${}{}{}$