# Does there exist a metric on $\mathbb{Q}$ which makes it compact?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Does there exist a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $(\mathbb{Q},d)$ is compact?

**EDIT**

> NOT considering $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Can there exist a metric on $\mathbb{Q}$ which makes it compact? We may decide later what does it do to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There are countable compact metric spaces.

Comment: Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly more explicit take on Tsemo's answer:

Define the injective map $\phi:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$\phi(0) = 0$ and if $q = { a \over b}$ where $a,b$ are coprime and $a \neq 0, b>0$ then
$\phi({a \over b}) = {1 \over b} (-1 + e^{i {7 \over 8} \pi {1 \over a}})$.
Let $d(q_1,q_2) = |\phi(q_1)-\phi(q_2)|$.

The following crude picture might help illustrate: [image]

Two important characteristics of $\phi$ are that
$\lim_{|a| \to \infty} \phi({a \over b}) = 0$ and $\lim_{b \to \infty} \phi({a \over b}) = 0$.

It is straightforward to verify that $d$ is indeed a metric.

It is sufficient to show that $(\mathbb{Q},d)$ is sequentially compact.

Suppose $q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $q_n = {a_n \over b_n}$ with $b_n \ge 1$, and $a_n,b_n$ coprime.

If $a_n = 0$ infinitely often then it is clear that there is a convergent subsequence (to zero), so
we can suppose $|a_n| \ge 1$.

If $(a_n,b_n)$ is bounded in the usual metric then it is clear that $(a_n,b_n)$ has some subsequence that converges to some $(a,b)$ (in fact we have $(a_n,b_n) = (a,b)$ infinitely often).

Otherwise either $|a_n|$ or $b_n$ is unbounded, and hence any corresponding subsequence converges to zero.

Note in particular that if the $q_n$ are all distinct then $q_n \to 0$.

Comment: This is neat! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $\{{1\over n},n\in\mathbb{N},n >0\}\cup\{0\}$ it is compact and there exists a bijection between this set and $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, but how to guarantee that that function is a homeomorphism?

Comment: The topology of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subtopological space of $\mathbb{R}$ is not complete, so it cannot be endowed with the topology of a compact metric space.

Comment: But completeness is not a topological property whereas compactness is.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627667/every-compact-metric-space-is-complete

Comment: So my question is same to ask that does there exist a metric on $\mathbb{Q}$ which makes it complete and totally bounded?

Comment: Completeness was a red herring.  $\mathbb Q$ is not **compact** (in the usual topology), so there is no homeomorphism from it to a compact space.

Comment: @RobertIsrael please see the edited version of my question. I am sorry if my question was misunderstood.

Comment: So take the metric corresponding to Tsemo's answer. That is, if $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb Q$ onto $\{1/n: n \in \mathbb N, n > 0\} \cup \{0\}$, you take the induced metric $d(r,s) = |f(r) - f(s)|$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I am sorry if I am missing something silly. Without the continuity of $f$ how does the compactness of the set flow to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: $f$ is not continuous with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb Q$, but you don't care about that topology.  It is continuous with respect to the topology given by the metric $d$, in fact by construction it is an isometry.