# Completeness of the Fell topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, descriptive-set-theory, polish-spaces

Recall that the Fell topology $\tau_F$ is a topology on the hyperspace $F(X)$ of closed subsets of a Hausdorff space (maybe you can define it in a more general context, but I am interested in $\mathbb{R}^n$). A prebase for the Fell topology is given by the sets of the form

$$\{ F\in F(X) : F\cap K =\emptyset  \} $$
$$\{ F\in F(X) : F\cap U \neq \emptyset  \}  $$

for some $K\subset X$ compact and some non-empty $U\subset X$ open.

I read in [1, Thm. 5.1.5] that $(F(\mathbb{R}^n),\tau_F)$ is compact metrizable, and becomes Polish if we restrict it to $(F(\mathbb{R}^n)\backslash \{\emptyset\},\tau_F)$. I assume that it is implicitly saying that $(F(\mathbb{R}^n),\tau_F)$ is not complete.

How can this be proved explicitly? I would guess that, since $(F(\mathbb{R}^n),\tau_F)$ is metric, there should be a Cauchy non-convergent sequence, but it is not clear to me what is the metric on $(F(\mathbb{R}^n),\tau_F)$.

---

[1]: *Beer, Gerald*, Topologies on closed and closed convex sets, Mathematics and its Applications (Dordrecht). 268. Dordrecht: Kluwer Academic Publishers. xi, 340 p. (1993). [ZBL0792.54008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0792.54008).

Comment: Since every compact metric space is complete, Beer's Theorem 5.1.5 says that $F(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ($=2^{\mathbb{R}^n}$) is completely metrisable.

Comment: Oh good point, you're right! I guess I should have thought about that... But does this mean that $F(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is Polish then? I wonder why Beer didn't say it explicitly, while he did for $F(\mathbb{R}^n\backslash \emptyset)$

Comment: He basically does if you read the proof of the implication $(2)\Rightarrow(3)$.

Comment: Well, thanks, I guess this answers the question. If you post it as an answer I will accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that every compact metric space [is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627667/every-compact-metric-space-is-complete). Since Beer proves in Theorem 5.1.5 that $F(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is compact and metrisable, it must be completely metrisable. I agree that Beer does not openly record this, but he does use it implicitly in the proof of the theorem.

btw, +1 for the well written question.